# Error in : Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am trying to print values from android to java desktop server. I am getting the value from other android class. After I get here, I am just trying to see if I get anything displayed. But Here I get the null pointer exception. It says that the client is null.

I don't know, where I am wrong. Can you please guide me for this.

I just want to pass value from android to java desktop server.  I hope it is clear.

This `onStart` is of the service which I have called.

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {               
    display();                          
    Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I have written this outside the class.

```
public void display() {
    PrintWriter printwriter;
    String messsage = "";

    final String IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.0.8";
    final int DEST_PORT = 4444;

    Socket client = null;
    try {
        client = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, DEST_PORT); // connect to server
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Write to server.
    try {

        printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream
        printwriter.flush();
        printwriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I should use `Asynctask`, then how I can use that ? As `NullPointerException` will exist only.

Stack Trace :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.wifisignalstrength.javaServiceClass@4175d9e8 with Intent { cmp=com.example.wifisignalstrength/.javaServiceClass (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2390)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:128)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)

dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.example.wifisignalstrength.javaServiceClass.display(javaServiceClass.java:80)
com.example.wifisignalstrength.javaServiceClass.onStart(javaServiceClass.java:40)
```

Comment: Add the stack trace here

Comment: Where is your logcat Error ?

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: the stack trace added

Comment: So which one is line 80?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask` as follows...

```
public class ClientAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        PrintWriter printwriter;
        String messsage = "";

        final String IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.0.8";
        final int DEST_PORT = 4444;

        Socket client = null;
        try {
            client = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, DEST_PORT); // connect to server
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Write to server.
        try {

            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream
            printwriter.flush();
            printwriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am unable to call Asynctask from the java service class. I tried calling asynctask execute method from onStart in Android. I tried keeping asynctask method in the java so asynctask was unable to execute. Getting error in new Asyntask.execute(message), when i keep it on start/oncreate in service class.

Answer (score 0):

If `client == null`, then `client.getOutputStream()` will rise a `NullPointerException`. so:

```
if (client != null)
{
    //Second 'try' here
}
```

Now, 192.168.0.8 is a private IP. Are both devices connected to the same internal network?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that `client` is null.  That's just a symptom.  Something went wrong on the line

```
client = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, DEST_PORT);
```

The bottom part of your stack trace comes from your `finally` block, after the exception in the line that I cited.  So you've actually got two complete stack traces, one after the other.

The *first* stack trace will tell you what's gone wrong.